# Discord: how to catch direct message from user to bot?

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

I am creating own bot for Discrod server. So far I have managed to give it commands like "!roll" into the chat and bot catches it replies "you rolled 6" to the chat as well.

```
client.UsingCommands(input => { input.PrefixChar = '!' });
command.CreateCommand("roll").Do(async (e) => { 
  await channel.SendMessage(username + " rolls " + rng.Next(1, 7)) });
```

But I dislike the way people are typing commands into the chat because it might be disruptive at some point. I would like to create a possibility to call command by direct message from the user to the bot. You'd DM bot "roll" and it will write to the chat "andrew rolled 1".

But I have no idea how to do that or if it is even possible. Any ideas?

Comment: You can make the bot delete the command message.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it as a solution in case I won't find an answer for direct message. Although I still prefer direct message solution because in some cases I'd like the bot to answer in direct message as well to avoid channel spam. Thanks for constructive reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution could be using Delegates/EventHandlers

```
    var client = new DiscordClient();
        client.MessageCreated += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (!e.Message.IsAuthor && e.Message.ToLower().Contains("roll")){
/*Code here*/
}       
            }
            EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> handler = new EventHandler<MessageEventArgs>(HandleMessageCreated);
            client.MessageCreated += handler;
```

Just make sure you place this delegate/EventHandler code below the Command Services setup, and the bot won't double-post when someone does `!roll`. 
Also, you can use `IsPrivate` variable on channel Object to check if the message sent on the channel is a DM/PM channel or not.

In case you need the documentations for Discord.NET v0.9.6, [here](http://rtd.discord.foxbot.me/en/legacy/index.html) it is.

Also, you may want to consider using Discord.NET v1.0.0+ instead.

Answer (score 4):

The current answers I found online were frustrating, this is how I did it (couldn't find any reference to the "Context" people kept saying, or the "IsPrivate"). Had to figure this stuff out just by inspecting the object themselves.

It appears the SocketMessage.Channel property changes from SocketTextChannel to SocketDMChannel depending on the source. Below is the method I made to determine if a message was a DM.

```
private bool IsPrivateMessage(SocketMessage msg) {
    return (msg.Channel.GetType() == typeof(SocketDMChannel));
}
```

Hope this helps someone save the 5 hours this wasted me :)

Comment: Simpler way: `msg.Channel is SocketDMChannel`